# Change giveninits option within document (BibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to know whether it is possible to change the `giveninits` option of `BibLaTeX` within the document, when having several bibliographies. In the MWE below I have two separate bibliographies in two `refsegments`. I would like the first to use full first names of the authors (`giveninits=false`), while the second should abbreviate first names to their initials (`giveninits=true`). `newrefcontext` does not seem to work for this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
    style=authoryear,%
    giveninits=false,%
    maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
%\DeclareRefcontext{inits}{giveninits=true}
\addbibresource{Lit.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{Lit.bib}
@ARTICLE{Aguilera-Franco:2001,
  author = {Noemi Aguilera-Franco and Ulises Hern\'{a}ndez-Romano and Peter A.
    Allison},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Biostratigraphy and Environmental Changes Across the {Cenomanian--Turonian}
    Boundary, Southern {Mexico}},
  journal = {Journal of South American Earth Sciences},
  volume = {14},
  number = {2},
  pages = {237--255},
  doi = {10.1016/S0895-9811(01)00014-1}
}

@ARTICLE{KrautwigEtAl:1998,
  author = {Dirk W. H. Krautwig and Lukas Hottinger and Heinrich Zankl},
  year = {1998},
  title = {The Lamellar-Perforate, Arborescent and Coloured Foraminifers \textit{Miniacina},
    \textit{Homotrema}, and \textit{Sporadotrema}},
  journal = {Facies},
  volume = {38},
  pages = {89--102},
  doi = {10.1007/BF02537359}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\newrefsegment
Test \textcite{Aguilera-Franco:2001} and \textcite{KrautwigEtAl:1998}.

\printbibliography[segment=1]

\section{Another section}
\newrefsegment
Test \textcite{Aguilera-Franco:2001}.

%\newrefcontext{inits} %DOES NOT WORK
\printbibliography[segment=2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just issue

```
\toggletrue{abx@bool@giveninits}
```

after the `\newrefcontext`.

The manual lists only `sorting`, `sortingnamekeyscheme` and `labelprefix` among the options that can be passed to `\DeclareRefcontext`. So you can't use `giveninits` there.

But `giveninits=true` only sets the toggle `abx@bool@#1inits`, so simply toggling it to true should give the expected result.